# Conditional group membership with Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to assign the group "webadmins" to a directory if the group already exists or set it to group "root" if it doesn't exist.

```
- getent:
    database=group
    key=webadmins
    fail_key=no

- debug:
    var=getent_group.webadmins    

- file:
    path=/var/www
    state=directory
    owner=root
    group="{{ (getent_group.webadmins == '') | ternary('root', 'webadmins') }}"
    mode=0775
```

The debug task returns this when the group doesn't exist:

```
ok: [host] => {
    "getent_group.webadmins": ""
}
```

But the value assigned to the group propriety is always "webadmins", even if the group doesn't exist, so it make my playbook to fail.

The group may exists in AD domain, so I cannot parse `/etc/group`.

Answer (score 1):

The following condition should work for you:

```
group="{{ (getent_group.webadmins is defined) | ternary('webadmins', 'root') }}"
```

---

If you displayed the value of `getent_group` in your debug task, you'd notice the value of `webgroup` key is actually set to `null`, not an empty string.

```
"getent_group": {
    "webgroup": null
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It still tries to set group to "webadmins" even when the group doesn't exist. I think the condition should be "is not defined" instead, anyway both make it returns the same thing.

Comment: So reverse the values in the filter instead of reversing the condition. And it does work, check again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this without using the ternary filter:

```
{{ 'webadmins' if getent_group.webadmins != '' else 'root' }}
```